# Validate input in Edittext after enter data in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout in my application like below: When i enter 100 from soft keyboard in edit text it should show correct answer toast automatically and it should allow only 3 numbers to enter in input text.

How to do this?

10 x 10 = ___

i tried with Textwatcher but its not working. When i enter correct answer EditText 10 X 10 should change to next value.

```
    int min = 0;
int max = 20;
Random r = new Random();
int mRandomOne = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
int mRandomTwo = r.nextInt(10 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        mFillAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fill);
    mFillAnswer.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(mOneValue.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(mTwoValue.getText().toString());

            int val = Integer.parseInt(mFillAnswer.getText().toString());
            if (val == (a * b)) {
                mOneValue.setText(String.valueOf(mRandomOne));
                mTwoValue.setText(String.valueOf(mRandomTwo));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            mOneValue.setText(String.valueOf(mRandomOne));
            mTwoValue.setText(String.valueOf(mRandomTwo));
        }
    });
```

Comment: specify where your errors are. some code will help us identify your problem

Comment: I don't think you would need to do anything inside `afterTextChanged` method

Comment: once enter correct value in Edit text ..question should be changed...in my case...10 x 10 = __..once i enter 100 here immeditaley question changed from 10 x 10 to next random question

Comment: can you make yourself clear. whats the result when you type in 100 ? from what i see it should change to a new question

Comment: after enter 100 in Edit text, question is not changing...still it shows 10 x 10                  mOneValue.setText(String.valueOf(mRandomOne));
mTwoValue.setText(String.valueOf(mRandomTwo));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For allowing only 3 numbers use `android:maxLength="3"` in your EditText
2. For automatically detecting the correct or incorrect answer use [TextWatcher](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-textwatcher-example)

**Update**
To change the TextView values:

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        //To avoid exception
        if(mFillerAnswer.getText().toString().equals("")){return;}

        int a = Integer.parseInt(mOneValue.getText().toString());
        int b = Integer.parseInt(mTwoValue.getText().toString());

        int val = Integer.parseInt(mFillAnswer.getText().toString());
        if (val == (a * b)) {
            //generate and use Random numbers here
            mOneValue.setText(r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
            mTwoValue.setText(r.nextInt(10 - 0 + 1) + 0);

            //to clear edit text
            mFillAnswer.setText("")
        }
    }
```

You were generating random numbers only once so it was pointless to be expecting newer values while the generation code is outside the TextWatcher scope

Comment: I don't see any problem in your textwatcher code. Why don't you do some logging inside the `onTextChanged` method if it is being called

Comment: after enter 100 in Edit text, question is not changing...still it shows 10 x 10

Comment: you have to generate the random values inside if statement not outside the whole TextWatcher code

Comment: Yes now it is working,,,,But EditText value is not cleared..it shows previous entered value...Once question change, EdiText field should be empty

Comment: add `mFillAnswer.setText("0")` inside the if statement and you are good to go

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""     in this line in inside if                                                                                                         int val = Integer.parseInt(mFillAnswer.getText().toString());

Comment: I know and I had been editing my answer to avoid. look at my updated answer

Comment: But it will not show entered value in Edit Text..because below code is in onTextChanged() mehod                                         if(mFillerAnswer.getText.toString().equals("")){return}

Comment: It will show coz the control is returned only when there is no input. Did you run and check it?

Comment: Functionality working..but number is not displaying in EditText....For example, 12 x 5 = _   ..if enter 60  it shows only 6 and last number is not showing ..immediately it moves to next question....if question 1 x 8 = _ ..if i  enter 8...8 is not showing in Edittext immeditaly i moves to next question

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy It is obviously the expected behaviour coz when you enter your last digit the answer matches and immediately clears the EditText. What is the problem here? If you want to display text a little longer introduce some delay inside the if statement before clearing the EditText

Comment: @ChaitanyaReddy since your issue in the question is solved, I think you should accept the answer

Comment: But User point view it would be good to show full out put before going to next question. Even if add thread.sleep(1000) before clearing edittext..still its not showing output in Edittext

Comment: well that wan an Up voted not accepted. You should tick it when accepting the answer. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: I think what you should do is create a button initially hiding it and when the answer is correct the button would be visible. Then when the user clicks on that button you should change the TextValues and clear the EditText